# Susy Next Alpha 4 cant hide grid "debug"

Tags: susy-compass

After updating to Rails4 / Susy Next Alpha 4 I always see the susy grid in development environment, although grid-background and similar are not activated / mentioned. Is there any setting I can deactivate "debug"?

Thank you in advance, ramsch

Comment: I was able to circumvent this issue by declaring the variable grid-color: 
`$grid-color     : white`

If someone knows a more solid way to achieve clean grids with Susy Next Alpha 4 I would love to here it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is set `$show-grids: hide;` which you can also do by passing the `hide` keyword to `set-grid` or `use-grid` for the shorthand.

Just to note, the variable is changing in the next pre-release, but the shorthand will stay the same. That will land in the next week or so.